# wordpress unset user_meta array value

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried the regular php unset, but without success.  Everything looks right here, but it remains in the array

```
$profileID = $_POST['profileID'];
$userID = $_POST['userID'];

    $reChkMetaValue = get_user_meta($userID,'friends',true);
    foreach($reChkMetaValue as $key => $value) {

if( ( $key = array_search($profileID, $reChkMetaValue) ) !== false );
    unset( $reChkMetaValue[$key] );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a foreach over the user meta. If the value of the data matches, log the key. then unset it from the array.

```
<?php
    $user_meta = get_user_meta($userID,'favs',true);
    $key_found = false;
    foreach($user_meta as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!$key_found){
             if($value == 'THE THING YOU WANT TO FIND'){
                 $remove_key = $key;
                 $key_found = true;
             }
        }
    }
    unset($user_meta[$remove_key]);
?>
```

Comment: I tried that, see modified code above.  For some reason the array item remains, but no errors are returned in the error log.

Comment: What are you trying to remove? why do you need to unset something form the array? why not just not display the data....